# How we can choose only 4 from a group of checkbox when the data is coming from the database

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I want to show JavaScript alert when user trying to choose more than four values from the group of checkbox the checkbox names are in array

```
<div class="checkbox alert alert-primary">

    <p><input type="checkbox" id="calorieCheckbox" name="txt_tradesman[]" value="<?php echo $restrad['tradesman_id'] ?>" onClick="return KeepCount()"><?php echo $restrad['fullname'] ?> <p>    

</div>
```

Comment: [StackOverflow isn't here to do your work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Show us what you have tried so far. We'll gladly help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's jQuery version:

> $('[name="txt_tradesman[]"]:checked').length